# Node.js with express.js returns 500 to ajax call

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, cordova, express

I have a cordova project where I do the following request.

```
$("#asd").on("click",function(){
    var data = {};
    data.title = "title";
    data.message = "message";

    $.ajax('127.0.0.1:3000/register', 
    {
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function() { console.log('success');},
        error  : function() { console.log('error');}
    });
});
```

Server side code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());


app.post('/register', function(req, res){
    var obj = {};
    console.log('body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    res.send(req.body);
});


app.listen(3000);
```

But I get `Internal Server Error 500` when I send the request. If I make a request simply by an html form or curl it just works fine.

What might be the cause of this?

Comment: you are getting an error in your server - read your terminal's output

Comment: Looks like CORS issue.

Comment: @dhilt how can I solve this issu can you help?

Comment: Try: `$.ajax('/register',` only

Comment: @TamBakaka Does the server, which serves static files run on a different port than Express server, not 3000?

Comment: @dhilt It runs on 3000 and with a basic html form request above code works.

Comment: @TamBakaka If the prot is the same, try to remove host from url on the client side: `$.ajax('/register', ...`

Comment: @dhilt '/register' gives me a 404 not found

Comment: @TamBakaka So who serves static files? Show its code please.

Comment: @dhilt I reduced the code so the whole application consists of the above code. still same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
        url:'/register',   //or 'localhost:3000/register'
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function() { console.log('success');},
        error  : function() { console.log('error');}
    });
```

Also you are required to use `cors()`

```
var cors = require('cors')

var app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

Also: https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

Comment: gives 404 not found

Comment: using localhost results in the same behavior

Comment: have you tried the syntax used above for ajax parameters?

Comment: yes did it turns out the error was req.body is undefined. How come does this happen?

Comment: first of all `express.bodyparser()` middleware is no longer available, what version you using?? should be `app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));`

Comment: this has solved my problem along with adjusting the order of app.use statements. Also enabling cors was required using app.use(cors()). Please edit your answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @TamBakaka added the cors()

Answer (score 0):

If it's related to the CORS, then you need to allow CORS on the server wich serves static via adding the following HTTP header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

[Here](https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html) is the example for Express (they put a wildcard `*` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:3000`).

Comment: did not help still the same issue

Answer (score -1):

Try JSON.stringify() in response

```
res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body));
```